# Adding multiple values to bar chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a simple bar chart in power bi that combines the number of orders received and the number of orders shipped in two separate columns so the two can be closely compared. I can't figure out how to go about this? In the data model I have an order date column, a shipment date column, an order day column (which has Mon, Tue, Wed etc...) and a shipment day column (again has Mon, Tue etc...). See below:

[image]

I have a measure which simply calculates the number of orders/shipments by counting the rows:

```
Volumes = COUNTROWS('DIM-Order')
```

Currently I have two separate bar charts. One displaying the number of orders taken on each week day:

[image]

The other displaying the number of orders shipped on each week day:

[image]

I would like these bar charts to be combined into one with the two separate values (each week day order and shipment volumes) so they can be closely compared.

New issue: I have is that the cluster chart is't displaying the correct values. See below. There are 1400 rows for orders on Sunday (this is 100% correct as I have filtered it in the data view) and in the cluster chart is shows the value as 0. All the other values seem to be incorrect as well.

Cluster chart:

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[image]

Comment: Do you wants Day wise SUM(order weekday number) and SUM(shipment weekday number) together?

Comment: Do you have a calendar table, you can them use USEREALTIONSHIP to combine these measures and calendar items to map correctly

Comment: @mkRabbani Yes I do. Jon, I have a separate 'Weekday' table which has two columns. 1 column for the weekday number (1 - 7) and one column for the weekday name (Mon, Tue, Wed etc...). Forgive me, I am not very experienced with Power BI. How would I go about using the USEREALTIONSHIP?

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply wants to compare your records by **Day** regardless any other breakdown, you can follow these below steps to achieve your requirements-

First go to **Power Query Editor** and create a new table using this below code. Suggesting new table as the source table might be related to other presentations.

```
let
    Source = your_source_table_name, //-- Use original table name
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"order day", "order weekday number", "shipment weekday number"}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {"order day"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

Now you will have data as below-

[image]

Now get back to your report by clicking **Close and Apply** button. Add a **Clustered Column Chart** in the report and configure as shown below-

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this mkRabbani. The only problem is that the 'order day' column is a column that was created in the data view of Power Bi desktop rather than in the query editor. When trying to create the table, I am getting the error: "Expression.Error: The column 'order day' of the table wasn't found"

Comment: Then create that column first in Power Query using the date column.

Comment: Hi, I've just done this but now I am getting the error: "The column 'order_weekday_number' of the table wasn't found." But the 'order_weekday_number' column is in the source table?

Comment: Don't worry I have resolved it. Going to try and implement the clustered column chart now....

Comment: Great! You can also use the Date column directly. That case you need to use Day part from hierarchy from date column during Chart configuration.

Comment: Ok so I have managed to create the cluster chart but the values don't seem to be correct. The order volumes for Sunday is showing as 0 when there should be 1400 orders for that weekday. I have edited the post with an image of the chart

Comment: Check data, probably no data for Sunday there. No way to behave differently for Sunday for the chart :) Do your other Day's data showing correctly?

Comment: I have filtered the data for the Sunday for orders and there are 1400 rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224521/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-bail-p).